# Showing open graph meta tags for link in iOS WhatsApp

Tags: facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, share-open-graph

There are two pages from two different sites

1. http://nastyazelenetskaya.pixlpark.ru/calendars
2. http://printkov.pixlpark.ru/prints/notepads

When I copy a link to the first one in iOS WhatsApp, tags don't display.

But for the second one, all tags show up without any issues.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9jUf.jpg

I use same meta tags on the both of them.

Tags in the

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://printkov.pixlpark.ru/prints/notepads">
<meta property="og:title" content="Печать блокнотов на заказ в Москве - онлайн-типография Принтков">
<meta property="og:description" content="Изготовление фирменных блокнотов на заказ в короткие сроки, печать на современном оборудовании с вашим логотипом, доставка по Москве и Московской области. ">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="printkov" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://printkov.pixlpark.ru/content/56bd7c5a33336a6ce5f5937c9b297870.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="printing" />
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://printkov.ru/calendars">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="nastyazelenetskaya" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Печать календарей ">
<meta property="og:description" content= "Печать всех типов календарей по банку готовых шаблонов, по вашему макету или с разработкой дизайна. ">
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://nastyazelenetskaya.pixlpark.ru/content/56bd7c5a33336a6ce5f5937c9b297870.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="printing" />
```

Tags in body

```
<span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="image/png"> 
      <link itemprop="url" href="http://printkov.pixlpark.ru/content/56bd7c5a33336a6ce5f5937c9b297870.jpg"> 
    </span>
    <link itemprop="thumbnailUrl" href="http://printkov.pixlpark.ru/content/56bd7c5a33336a6ce5f5937c9b297870.jpg"> 
<span itemprop="thumbnail" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"> 
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://printkov.pixlpark.ru/content/56bd7c5a33336a6ce5f5937c9b297870.jpg"> 
</span>
```

```
<link itemprop="thumbnailUrl" href="http://nastyazelenetskaya.pixlpark.ru/content/56bd7c5a33336a6ce5f5937c9b297870.jpg"> 
<span itemprop="thumbnail" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"> 
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://nastyazelenetskaya.pixlpark.ru/content/56bd7c5a33336a6ce5f5937c9b297870.jpg"> 
</span>
<span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="image/png"> 
      <link itemprop="url" href="http://nastyazelenetskaya.pixlpark.ru/content/56bd7c5a33336a6ce5f5937c9b297870.jpg"> 
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

the site should be SSL certificate. It should not be self signed but CA one.
The image should be served by SSL CA basically